# How to add source path record in Fluentd?

Tags: logging, config, fluentd, syslog, collectors

My fluentd config:

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5140
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag rsyslog
</source>

<filter>
 @type record_transformer
 enable_ruby
   <record>
     hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
     tag ${tag_parts[0]}
     severity ${tag_parts[1]}
     facility ${tag_parts[2]}
  </record>
</filter>


<match rsyslog.*.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host localhost
  port 9200
  logstash_format true
</match>
```

How to extract from syslog log files the source path by facility (auth,daemon ...)?

Comment: Please share what you want to achive. An input and the desired output. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.